# Testing page content after redirect not working

Tags: python, django, testing

I am writing a simple unit test method which tests that a view is redirecting after receiving a POST. I can test the expected URL matches the response object but not the content.

Current shoddy code:

```
def test_example_view_redirects_to_home_after_post(self):
    client = Client()
    response = client.post('/example/')

    # Test location
    self.assertEqual(response.get('location'), "http://testserver/")

    # Test page content
    expected_template = render_to_string('home.html')
    self.assertEqual(response.content, expected_template)
```

The test is failing:

```
  AssertionError: b'' != '<html> etc etc...
```

The view code can be ultra simple at this stage:

```
def example(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else:
        return render(request, 'example.html')
```

I am new to TDD and just wondering why this isn't working as I might expect it to.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can use `follow=True` in your `client.post` which will emulate the browser following the redirect to the next page. [See here in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Client.post). That will allow you to test the second page's content with `assertContains`.
2. You can use `assertRedirects` to test that the redirect happens properly. Check that out [here in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.SimpleTestCase.assertRedirects).

Comment: Brilliant thank-you. I initially tried assertRedirects but with no joy.. now I know why. Marking correct.